# Adding RTL support in the html xml namespace (xmlns) tag for multiple xhtml files using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, xhtml

So, I have extracted an Epub file (which is in Arabic text) 
and I want to edit all the .xhtml files in it to have rtl support ...

from this:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

to this:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="rtl" lang="ar" xml:lang="ar">
```

as I don't want to edit each xhtml file individually

Help on how I can go about doing this would greatly appreciated

[1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/I45An.jpg"where the editing script will be"

[2]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi9cm.jpg"where the xhtml files are located"

Comment: was looking for some optimal solution but I ended up using the ol' fashioned way and just writing a python script 

    import os
    import sys


    for filepath in glob.iglob('./Text/*.xhtml', recursive=True):
        with open(filepath) as file:
            s = file.read()
            s = s.replace('<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">', '<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="rtl" lang="ar" xml:lang="ar">')
        with open(filepath, "w") as file:
            file.write(s)